# Localizing at a prime ideal, specific computation

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

If $q \in \mathbb N$ and $q = p_1^{n_1} ... p_j^{n_i}$ where all of the $p_i$ are prime numbers then the prime ideals of $\mathbb Z / q\mathbb Z$ are all the $(p_i)$. What happens when we localize $\mathbb Z / q \mathbb Z$ at $(p_i)$? I think we should get the ring $\mathbb Z / p_i^{n_i} \mathbb Z$ but don't really know how to prove it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ and let $x=q/p_i^{n_i}$ considered as an element of $A$.  Note that $x\not\in (p_i)$ and thus is inverted in the localization $A_{(p_i)}$, and $xp_i^{n_i}=0$ in $A$.  Thus, the localization map $A\to A_{(p_i)}$ factors through the quotient $A\to A/(p_i^{n_i})$.  Moreover, every element of $A\setminus(p_i)$ maps to a unit in $A/(p_i^{n_i})\cong\mathbb{Z}/p_i^{n_i}\mathbb{Z}$, and so the factoring map $A/(p_i^{n_i})\to A_{(p_i)}$ is actually an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Use the *Chinese remainder theorem*:
$$\mathbf Z.\mathbf Z\simeq \mathbf Z/p_1^{n_1}\mathbf Z\times\dots\times \mathbf Z/p_j^{n_j}\mathbf Z.$$
and use that localisation commutes with direct sums.

Comment: I would do this but am actually trying to *prove* the chinese remainder theorem using this lemma about localization!

Comment: Isn't it a basic tool for you?

Comment: I meant that I'm trying to prove the chinese remainder theorem using the lemma in my question, namely that localizing $\mathbb Z/ q \mathbb Z$ at $(p_i)$ gives us $\mathbb Z/ p_i \mathbb Z$. Not the lemma you mention, that localization commutes with direct sums. I worded it weirdly!

Comment: It gives $\mathbf Z_{(p_i)}/p_i^{n_i}\mathbf Z_{(p_i)}$.